# The meaning of the calendar owner's email in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What is the meaning of the owner's email in calendar property [1] ?

Is it the owner's SMTP address, userPrincipalName or the other property of user resources [2]?

Ref.
[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties):

> Owner - [emailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/emailaddress?view=graph-rest-1.0) - If set, this represents the user who created or added the calendar. For a calendar that the user created or added, the owner property is set to the user. For a calendar shared with the user, the owner property is set to the person who shared that calendar with the user.

It's an [emailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/emailaddress?view=graph-rest-1.0) which is a simple object containing the user's name and address:

```
{
  "address": "string",
  "name": "string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, my question is that the emailAddress is owner's UPN or another property of owner?

Comment: If it's in your tenant then it will be their UPN. External users don't have a UPN in your tenant.